# How to separate and move nonnegative and positive values between arrays?

Tags: c#

How to write a method which moves nonnegative values (found in two given arrays) into the first array, then moves negative values (found in two given arrays) into the second array? For example: for {1, -2, 5} and {-2, 4, -9} we should receive {1, 5, 4} and {-2, -2, -9}. The even split between nonnegative/negative numbers is not guaranteed. The sizes of arrays can be changed.

```
    static void Arrays(ref int[] tab1, ref int[] tab2){
        int[] tempNegative = new int[3];
        int[] tempNonNegative = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < tab1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tab2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (tab1[j] < 0)
                {
                    tempNegative[j] = tab1[j];
                }
                else
                {
                    tempNonNegative[i] = tab1[j];
                }
            }

        }

        tab1 = tempNonNegative;
        tab2 = tempNegative;
    }
```

After using this method in a main program I received {5, 5, 5} and {0, -2, 0}. I know that there should be another loop for checking values in the second array. The question is how to put a value in a proper position in those arrays?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.  If you edit your question with your good-faith attempt at this, we would be happy to *help* you.  We are less keen on doing your homework *for* you, though.  The link to edit the question is directly under the question.

Comment: Some things to think about when improving your question: Do you have to _move_ the items or could you just create two new arrays? Do you have to keep the sizes of the arrays fixed? Are you guaranteed to have an even split between positive/negative numbers? You could do this in one line with Linq but I suspect this is an assignment to get you to use specific techniques.

Comment: Easiest way is to create 2 new arrays and loop through given 2. Put negative in first array and positive in second.

Comment: I edited my question a  bit. Could you please take a look now?

Comment: Make sure you get your terminology right. The sizes of arrays in .NET **can not be changed**. `ref` doesn't change that, you're simply replacing the arrays with new arrays with new sizes. It's like having two buildings built, then you want to rearrange all the furniture, and instead of moving furniture between the two, you build two new buildings capable of holding the furniture for building A and B and move it out of the two original ones. It's not the same thing. Basically, stating that "The sizes of arrays can be changed" means you're not using .NET, or you're mistaken.

Comment: Following up on @LasseV.Karlsen 's comment, even `Array.Resize` does not *actually* resize the passed in array.  It creates a new array, copies the elements to the new array, then gives you the new array back.  The original array remains unmodified, sad and forgotten.  Arrays in C# cannot be resized, even with a function whose name implies precisely that.

Comment: If you're allowed to replace the arrays, you can simply shorten the whole method down to these 3 statements: `int[] negatives = tab1.Concat(tab2).Where(i => i < 0).ToArray(); tab1 = tab1.Concat(tab2).Where(i => i >= 0).ToArray(); tab2 = negatives;`.

Comment: I didn't describe it precisely. I meant that the number of nonnegative or positive values can be different than exact size of the array (which was "3" in the given example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 pieces of evidence in your question which leads me to the following way to solve it:

1. You state that "The sizes of arrays can be changed"
2. You use `ref` when declaring the parameters to the method

I've already commented why the first one is actually a fallacy, but these two taken together means that there's two ways of writing the solution to your question.

1. Using LINQ
2. Doing it manually

I'll do it manually first.

The easiest way is to declare two lists, put each number into one if it is a negative and the other if it isn't, and then reassign the parameters to a new array at the end, like this:

```
static void Arrays(ref int[] tab1, ref int[] tab2)
{
    var negatives = new List<int>();
    var positives = new List<int>();

    foreach (var item in tab1)
        if (item < 0)
            negatives.Add(item);
        else
            positives.Add(item);
    foreach (var item in tab2)
        if (item < 0)
            negatives.Add(item);
        else
            positives.Add(item);

    tab1 = positives.ToArray();
    tab2 = negatives.ToArray();
}
```

Now, if we allow a *slight* bit of LINQ we can combine the two arrays into one collection, and thus go down to one foreach:

```
static void Arrays(ref int[] tab1, ref int[] tab2)
{
    var negatives = new List<int>();
    var positives = new List<int>();

    foreach (var item in tab1.Concat(tab2))
        if (item < 0)
            negatives.Add(item);
        else
            positives.Add(item);

    tab1 = positives.ToArray();
    tab2 = negatives.ToArray();
}
```

The second approach is to use LINQ altogether:

```
static void Arrays(ref int[] tab1, ref int[] tab2)
{
    var negatives = tab1.Concat(tab2).Where(i => i < 0).ToArray();
    tab1 = tab1.Concat(tab2).Where(i => i >= 0).ToArray();
    tab2 = negatives;
}
```

It has to use a temp variable, `negatives`, otherwise we'd destroy the contents of `tab2` before we got to working out what to put in `tab1`.

If we rewrite the whole method using newer C# syntax, such as Expression-bodied members (C# 6+) and Tuples (C# 7+), we get:

```
static void Arrays(ref int[] tab1, ref int[] tab2)
    => (tab1, tab2) = (
        tab1.Concat(tab2).Where(i => i >= 0).ToArray(),
        tab1.Concat(tab2).Where(i => i < 0).ToArray()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy task with 2 indexes, I'll write the pseudocode:

```
int pos = 0, neg = 0; 

for(int i = 0; i < tab1.Length(); i++){
    if(tab1[i] < 0) tempNegative[neg++] = tab1[i];
    else tempNonNegative[pos++] = tab1[i];
}
for(int i = 0; i < tab2.Length(); i++){
    if(tab2[i] < 0) tempNegative[neg++] = tab2[i];
    else tempNonNegative[pos++] = tab2[i];
}
```

This should do the trick. The algorithm loops through both arrays and put their values in the right arrays.